# document.addForm.submit() not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

addForm is used as the form id, but the form submit is not working in firefox.

```
$(function() {
 var date = $("#todo_due").val();
 var text = $("#todo_due").val();
  if (date && text) {
    document.addForm.submit();
  } else if (!date && !text) {
    new Messi('{$LANG.main.todo_validation}', {ldelim}title: '{$LANG.error.error}', titleClass: 'info', modal: true{rdelim});
  } else if (!text) {
    new Messi('{$LANG.main.todo_validation_desc}', {ldelim}title: '{$LANG.error.error}', titleClass: 'info', modal: true{rdelim});
  } else {
    new Messi('{$LANG.main.todo_validation_date}', {ldelim}title: '{$LANG.error.error}', titleClass: 'info', modal: true{rdelim});
  }
});
```

Comment: the form must be submited with respect to addform id...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById('addForm').submit();
```

or

```
$('#addForm').submit();
```

for a cross browser solution.

Internet Explorer adds a global variable called `addForm` because you have an element having this ID but it's an incorrect and non standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use jquery. You can easyly submit the form by:

```
$("#addForm").submit();
```